# Web app roll out

Tags: facebook, deployment, sails.js, web-deployment

I've been developing web apps some years now, actually as a hobby. When I write something, unsing Laravel, Sails.js, or Meteor and I add a feature, I upload it and it's there, for everyone.

However, I've always been wondering how bigger sites like facebook manage to roll out features to just some users. Do they push their changes to just some servers? But in that case - how do they manage the make the selected users access just these servers?
Or some db entry to see if the user has access to the feature/ version?

So how does it work?

Really interested in this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large sites like Facebook use a technique called [Feature toggles](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html) to control the functionality that is active at run-time. The following blog article describes Facebook's approach:

https://abhishek-tiwari.com/post/decoupling-deployment-and-release-feature-toggles

Comment: Please make the URL `https`